# replace __defineGetter__ and __defineSetter__ on the prototype with defineProperty

Tags: javascript

I currently use the following syntax to define a class with getters and setters.

```
SomeObject = function() {

  this._propertyOne = 'test';

}

SomeObject.prototype.__defineGetter__('propertyOne', function() {

  return this._propertyOne;

});

SomeObject.prototype.__defineSetter__('propertyOne', function(value) {

  this._propertyOne = value;

});
```

Then I can access the property like this:

```
var o = new SomeObject();
o.propertyOne = 'test2';
console.log(o.propertyOne);
```

How can I achieve the same with the non-deprecated defineProperty command or something similiar?

I tried something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(SomeObject.prototype, 'propertyOne', {
  get: function() {

    return this._propertyOne;

  }.bind(this),
  set: function(value) {

    this._propertyOne = value;

  }.bind(this)
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment you run `Object.defineProperty`, the `this` value is not what you want it to be, but `window` (or the object that you run that snippet from). So this is what actually happens:

```
Object.defineProperty(SomeObject.prototype, 'propertyOne', {
  get: function() {

    return this._propertyOne;

  }.bind(window),
  set: function(value) {

    this._propertyOne = value;

  }.bind(window)
});
```

Remove the `.bind(this)` part, and it should work fine.